# Symfony - Doctrine: migration with multiple schema failed

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

**Environnement:**

- php 8.1
- symfony 5.4
- doctrine/dbal 3.3
- doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.7
- doctrine/migrations 3.5.1
- postgresql 14.4

**My problem is the following;**
We have a database containing several schema to separate the data useful to the system and those published directly to users.
We use of course the classic entity declaration with Symfony & Doctrine:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="stats", schema="system")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\System\StatsRepository")
 */
class Stats
```

The problem is that when we delete a relation between the `public` schema and the `system` schema, the migration generated by the command `bin/console doctrine:schema:update` has an error when deleting the index.
**Here is the migration generated:**

```php
    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('DROP INDEX idx_2225600edc6d4b4b');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE system.stats DROP article_id');
    }
```

The problem being that in deleting the index, the line forgets to specify that the index comes from the `system` schema.
**We need:**

```php
$this->addSql('DROP INDEX system.idx_2225600edc6d4b4b');
```

We want to keep the `bin/console doctrine:schema:update` operation for updating the database, but this problem now forces us to use the migration system to change the drop index.

I know that the obvious solution would be to use the migration system (`bin/console make:migration`) but this implies some changes in the IC. That's why I'm wondering; **have you ever had this problem? If yes, how did you solve the problem?**

Comment: Is explicit index declaration is fine for your project codebase? If yes, then try to add index to @ORM\Table(..., indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_...", columns={"stats"})}) or maybe just as another annotation @ORM\Index(name="idx_2225600edc6d4b4b", columns={"stats"}). And, maybe, it's better to use attributes with 8.1: #[ORM\Index(name: 'idx_...', columns=['stats'])]

Comment: @yaroslavche, I tried adding the declaration of the index in the entity, it does not cause any modification on the migration or the update of the database